# Specifics on ImageMagick and animated GIFs

Tags: gif

I've looked through several StackExchange threads without specifics on how ImageMagick is tied into Craft. Web host says the binary is installed on server but not the module. Is the PHP module required?

> we looked into this further, and found that we do not have the ImageMagick PHP module installed, but we do have the binary. I'm not sure if Craft needs the PHP module, but if it does, that would be the reason for this not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [Craft](https://craftcms.com/docs/requirements#optional-php-extensions) to use it, yes the ImageMagick PHP extension is required because Craft uses [PHP's bindings](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/36010cd04207eae1c5cb4c8be133cf85454b4f84/app/vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Imagick/Imagine.php) in the library they're using.

Depending on the host's OS, it should be a package manager update away. Any decent host should be able get it working incident free.